# Derivative at Endpoint

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

In Rudin's "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" he defines the limit of a function as follows.

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be metric spaces; suppose $E \subset X$, $f$ maps $E$ into $Y$, and $p$ is a limit point of $E$.  Then
>   $$
> \lim_{x \to p} f(x) = q
> $$
>   if there is a point $q \in Y$ with the following property: For every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that
>   $$
> d_Y(f(x),q) < \epsilon
> $$
>   for all points $x \in E$ for which
>   $$
> 0 < d_X(x,p) < \delta.
> $$

The functions $d_X$ and $d_Y$ are the metrics on $X$ and $Y$, respectively.  He then defines the derivative of a real function as follows.

> Let $f$ be defined on $[a,b]$.  For any $x \in [a,b]$ form the quotient
>   $$
> \phi(t) = \frac{f(t) - f(x)}{t - x} \qquad a < t < b,\, t \neq x,
> $$
>   and define
>   $$
> f^\prime(x) = \lim_{t \to x}\, \phi(t), \qquad (1)
> $$
>   provided this limit exists in accordance with [the above definition].  We thus associate with the function $f$ a function $f^\prime$ whose domain is the set of points $x$ at which the limit (1) exists.

**I can't reconcile what's wrong with derivatives at endpoints**.  As a concrete example, let $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x) = x^2$.  I claim that $f^\prime(0) = 0$.  Indeed, the difference quotient is
$$
\phi(t) = \frac{t^2 - 0^2}{t - 0} = t
$$
and so we need to show
$$
\lim_{t \to 0}\, t = 0.
$$
Let $\epsilon > 0$ and choose $\delta = \epsilon$.  Then for all $t \in [0,1]$ such that $0 < |t| < \delta$ we have $|t| < \epsilon$.  Hence $f^\prime(0) = 0$, even though it is at an endpoint of the domain of $f$.

In particular, there's no use to introduce one-sided derivatives.  Am I missing something?

Comment: There is use to introduce one-sided derivatives. For functions like $f \colon [-1,1] \to \mathbb{R},\, x \mapsto \lvert x\rvert$. If the world ends at $a$, then the derivative at $a$ and the one-sided derivative at $a$ are the same. If the world doesn't end at $a$, the concepts are different.

Comment: Could you state your question clearly ? What is "wrong" with derivatives ?

Answer (score 3):

I only can say that you are right in everything you write. This is an issue of definition. Rudin simply allows endpoints of the interval of definition of $f$ to be in the domain of the derivative. Others don't or only consider open intervals.